# Unstoppable application in Windows

Tags: c#, winforms

This question may be some times funny for all. Created an application in `c#` but my problem is in implementing that, the application should not be stopped in any case with out system restart. How can i do this? I heard about circular reference what is it and how can i apply it in my windows application

if it can be done using windows service then service can also be stopped from task manager but i don't want my application to stop

Comment: What are you trying to create? A user should be able to close your program if they really want to.

Comment: i am trying to create a parental control application which should not be stopped when started unless system restarts

Comment: But if it can be closed when the system restarts, won't the child be able to just restart the system? If you create it as a service and the child is able to find and shutdown the service, they'll likely be able to simply restart the PC to close it.

Comment: no it will come in startup so that again it will work

Comment: That can still be disabled. It's not much harder to remove it from the startup list via msconfig than it is to find a service and shut it down.

Comment: yz that can be possible but i want that user can't close the application from endtask window

Comment: Create a service. Apply proper permissions so user can't stop services. Profit. No need to solve this from code (or solve it at all as it has been hundreds of times).

Answer (score 0):

you can not do this, since the application can be closed using Task Manger. So the only way is to create two processes first represent your app second to check if your app is closed run it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a service, as suggested in one comment. This will prevent people without administrative controls from stopping it. If people *do* have administrative control, they will be able to stop your program quite easily.

I checked for tricks kids use to go around Net Nanny. The most common trick is to install a virtual machine and use that for accessing the network. Users who aren't administrators can't install Virtual Box or the like, so the service solution will work against these, as well.