# link app with windows service like shut down so that process never end?

Tags: c#, process, taskmanager

link app with windows process so that when user terminated or end the process it says used by another process and also need to insert it into system file like shutdown file using c sharp so that my app never end or terminates 
i tried that material but not usefull

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

I also tried that code in click:

```
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
if (!WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsSystem)
{
   ctx = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.IntPtr.Zero);
}
string thisuser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

But have a look at image it is still present in process, what I want is that my process never stops.

[image]

Comment: i tried every solution on net like 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716567/launch-process-and-hide-command-line-parameters-from-task-manager.'

Comment: and many other solutions from stack over flow so it mean it is not  Duplicate questiobn

Answer (score 0):

> what I want is that my process never stops.

To ensure that your process is always running and is started when Windows boots it's easiest to create a windows service instead. It will probably still show up somewhere in task manager and could be killed manually by the user. But windows will try to keep it running.

How to create a service:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

And if you need other programs to communicate with your service I find it easy to use a WCF service instead.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx

Comment: can you tell me how to link your app with windows builtin service so that when process terminated from window manager it return used by another process

Comment: i think this is the only best solution we have there and also i have modified the question kindly view that again\

Comment: Even if it returns as "used by another process" a user could still terminate the second process and then your process.
Maybe a windows service accessible only to administrators that checks so your application is always running? 
Se also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476063/unstoppable-application-in-windows